Reassigning pandas columns in chained .assign() gives incorrect values
I often follow the convention (for better or worse) of loading data and preprocessing manipulations in a single line of chained pandas commands. In one such manipulation, I need to multiply a set of columns by a scalar value and thought I could achieve this using .assign(**kwargs) syntax with an appropriate dictionary of keyword-callable pairs. However, in doing so, I end up with incorrect values. It's likely I'm overlooking some problem related to dict-comprehension, mutable objects, and/or lambda functions. I'm hoping someone can inform me as to why/what is happening in the attached minimum working example. Any suggestions as to better practices are also welcome. Thanks in advance.
import sys
import pandas as pd

print(f'python version: {sys.version.split()[0]}')
print(f'pandas version: {pd.__version__}\n')

# dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'i1': [0.001, -0.30, -0.018, 0., 0.],
                   'i2': [0.001, -0.029, -0.007, 0., 0.],
                   'i3': [0., -0.03, -0.004, 0., 0.]})
print('##### df')
print(df)

# re-assigned dataframe: values are different from df, expected to be the same
# looks like i3 is simply copied into i1 and i2
print('\n##### df after reassignment')
df2 = df.assign(**{key: lambda df: 1*df[key] for key in ['i1', 'i2', 'i3']})
print(df2)


# piped dataframe: values are same as df, expected to be the same
def pipe_func(df, keys):
    df[keys] = 1*df[keys]
    return df


print('\n##### df after pipe_func')
df3 = df.pipe(pipe_func, keys=['i1', 'i2', 'i3'])
print(df3)

My output:
python version: 3.9.16
pandas version: 2.0.3

##### df
      i1     i2     i3
0  0.001  0.001  0.000
1 -0.300 -0.029 -0.030
2 -0.018 -0.007 -0.004
3  0.000  0.000  0.000
4  0.000  0.000  0.000

##### df after reassignment
      i1     i2     i3
0  0.000  0.000  0.000
1 -0.030 -0.030 -0.030
2 -0.004 -0.004 -0.004
3  0.000  0.000  0.000
4  0.000  0.000  0.000

##### df after pipe_func
      i1     i2     i3
0  0.001  0.001  0.000
1 -0.300 -0.029 -0.030
2 -0.018 -0.007 -0.004
3  0.000  0.000  0.000
4  0.000  0.000  0.000


You need to use df.assign(**{key: lambda df, key=key: 1*df[key] for key in ['i1', 'i2', 'i3']})

@mozway thank you. This fixes my problem, late-binding was indeed my issue.
